# Automatic Command from output

Tags: jupyter-notebook

**First code Automatically Print Second Code Result ?**

#input first code

```
a='apple'
b='book'
c='command'
command = "abc"
print(",".join(command))
```

#output

```
a,b,c
```

is There Anyway , Output Result Automatically Print Like This.

input second code

```
a='apple'
b='book'
c='command'
print (a,b,c)
```

output

```
apple book command
```

Comment: What language is this question related to? Please edit the question and tag it appropriately. FYI, "Combine" is a tag for a certain Apple's framework, so not related to your question.

Comment: Thanks for guidance